# List union algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to work on a list union algorithm now, with the following specifications: if an element in L1 occurs in L1 more than it occurs in L2, the union should return the maximum number of occurrences, i.e the amount it occurs in L1, with the roles of L1 and L2 switched if an element occurs in L2 more than it occurs in L1. If L1 and L2 are disjoint, the union just returns the regular set union. So far my thought process has been:

1. Iterate through L1.
2. Check if any element in L1 is also in L2.
3. If an element in L1 is also in L2, check which list has the greater `count` of the element.
4. If L1 and L2 are disjoint, return regular set union.
5. Repeat step 3 with L2 and L1 reversed.
6. Return the union.

I was thinking about using the `max` function to kind of tell Python to return the list where the multiplicity of each element in the union is the maximum number of occurrences of the element in both L1 and L2. Ideas?

Comment: Please post your current implementation.

Comment: Seems like a job for a `collections.Counter` ...

Comment: I'm aware of the `collections.Counter` implementation. Transforming this into a dictionary will make this much easier. Good idea.

Comment: Please also post your test cases with the expected output

Comment: Do you need to know how Python solves this problem efficiently, or do you need to write an algorithm with only basic tools (homework, etc.)?

Answer (score 4):

This is a perfect job for the `collections` standard module, which offers multisets:

```
from collections import Counter

result_list = list((Counter(list1)|Counter(list2)).elements())
```

A `Counter` object represents here a multiset (set of generally more than 1 copy of its elements), the union operator `|` keeps the maximum count of each element, and `elements()` returns an iterator where each element is returned the number of times corresponding to its count.

If you don't really need a list but can work with a multiset in the code, then `Counter(list1) | Counter(list2)` is the union [multiset](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) that you need.

Comment: Cool. This is much better than my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(L1)
for value, count in Counter(L2).items()
    counts[value] = max(counts[value], count)
newlist = [value for value, count in counts.items() for _ in range(count)]
```

Comment: `[value for value, count in counts.items() for _ in range(count)]` could also be `sum([value]*count for value, count in count.items(), [])`: it has the advantage of showing a tad more directly the structure of the final list (repetition of values).

Comment: @EOL, sum is only efficient for numeric types. For lists it has quadratic performance (O(n**2)). `list` with `.elements()` as you used is probably the best way

Comment: I agree: using `sum()` is only good for its slightly improved legibility. :) Your list comprehension has linear performance, which is way better.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably just use dicts with counts as values. Union logic is:

```
counts = {i: max(L1.get(i,0), L2.get(i,0)) for i in set(L1)|set(L2) }
```

The final list is

```
newlist = [value for value, count in counts.items() for _ in range(count)]
```

Comment: I simplified the calculation of the union of keys. This is a good, "manual" way of obtaining the same thing as `dict(Counter(L1)|Counter(L2))` (with `from collections import Counter`). However, the `Counter` class along with its union operator is meant to do just this, with the advantage that the code is more explicit.

Comment: I also added the construction of the result list, since this is what the question asks for.

Answer (score -1):

a solution using only lists and their max/min properties could be

```
union = [] 
[union.extend([n] * max(l1.count(n), l2.count(n))) for n in range (min(min(l1),min(l2)), max(max(l1),max(l2))+1)]
```

Comment: This can be extremely inefficient, as this solution goes through all possible values (`l1 = [0]` and `l2 = [2**1000]`); also, `count()` requires each list to be gone through for each possible value, which also takes a relatively long time. This solution also supposes that the elements in the lists are integers: this is unnecessarily restrictive. Dictionary- or Counter-based solutions are both much faster and more general.